# Parallel data loading in browser

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, promise

We have a script, that load some data from server.

```
'use strict';

let data;           // Here will be stored data from server
let url = '...';    // Here some correct URL

(async () => {

    let response = await fetch(url);    // Load response
    data = await response.text();       // Load full data and save as text

    // Some work with data from server

})();

// The enormous script below
```

In async IIFE `fetch()` creates a new promise and last is pushed to the *microtask queue*. And it will pop from this queue only after executing full script. It's clear, this behavior is a reason to use promises.

**QUESTION:**

Will loading data go parallel with executing JavaScript code, which is below the IIFE, and than will execute tasks (promises) from *microtasks queue*? Or firstly will execute JavaScript code, which is below the IIFE, then data will be loaded from server and finally will executes microtasks?